# Device Token for Push Notifications

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I have Production Certificate & provisioning profile for my app. I have been using the same since over a month. I have various builds created over this time.

Suddenly the same build stopped generating device token for my application. Also the previously created ipa builds wont work. I have not made any changes on my developer account or the credentials used for the same.

I have also verified that there is no problem in the code. Other certificate and provisioning profile work perfectly.

What could be the possible reason for stop in generation of device token?

Answer (score 0):

Since none of my certificates were generating a token, I revoked them and created new a one.

Now it working. Though Im not sure why this scenario would arise.